# CMV load time efficiencies

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, configurable-map-viewer

How do I get CMV to start up more efficiently.
Exploring ArcMap GENERAL start services immediately check box (to un check it).
ArcMap Caching is set to Dynamic from data, levels 9 - 17, 5MB estimated RAM.
Looking for ways to delay start of CMV layers and widgets so CMV appears sooner.